# Right Click Menu on Windows Button in Windows XP / VISTA

Tags: windows-vista

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows: How to remove items from the right click (context) menu?](https://superuser.com/questions/5011/windows-how-to-remove-items-from-the-right-click-context-menu)

When I Right-Click on 'Start Button', it shows a whole bunch of Options in addition to regular ones like 'Open', 'Explore', 'Properties', 'Open all Users' & 'Explore All Users'. I really dont want all the other options.

Can anyone please help me how to remove those unwanted entries in there ? I have both Windows XP Pro & VISTA.

thanks
Rahul

Comment: It might be helpful if, instead of describing the menu items you dont mind, you described the ones you don't. I have windows 7 and right clicking on my start buttons shows me only two options - properties (for the start menu and taskbar) and "launch windows explorer" - which just launches browsing my computer generally, not any start menu specific folder.

Answer (score 2):

That is based on an explorer context menu - and those are controlled by registry entries - see this:

http://www.technobabble.com.au/technobabble/html/tweaks/context-menus.htm

or this: http://windowsxp.mvps.org/context_folders.htm

Note this will affect right-clicking on files and folders as well...