# Is there a way to clean-up the Windows right-click menu?

Tags: windows, context-menu, right-click

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows: How to remove items from the right click (context) menu?](https://superuser.com/questions/5011/windows-how-to-remove-items-from-the-right-click-context-menu)

I've heard the right click menu called the 'Context Menu' but I'm looking for an application or method to remove all entries, sans a few.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean the context menu in Windows Explorer only? You may get better answers if you clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a great article [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-clean-up-your-messy-windows-context-menu/) about the hows and whys of this.  If you scroll past the messy stuff, there's links to a couple of tools that make it easy.  (I am unsure if they officially support Win7 but they do support Vista, and the mechanics of this haven't CHANGED so I assume they still work.)

Answer (score 1):

Not by default, no.  What's in any particular context menu is determined by the application itself.  However it was coded by the developers, that's what it will show.  You can, however, make use of extenders and utilities to try and alter what's in here, but most of them focus on adding additional entries.  Those that try to hide things work with varying degrees of success.

One example you can find [here](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/right-click-context-menu-extender-for-windows-7-released):  This one focuses on adding new functionality to the base Windows 7 right click menu.