# How to remove unimportant items from desktop right click context menu?

Tags: windows-7, context-menu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows: How to remove items from the right click (context) menu?](https://superuser.com/questions/5011/windows-how-to-remove-items-from-the-right-click-context-menu)

I've recently installed Intel's video card driver, and now I have 3 items added to my desktop's right click context menu that I really don't want.

How do I remove them?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways:

1. download this [utility](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html) which allows you to disable context menu items.
2. Edit the registry, as discussed [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-clean-up-your-messy-windows-context-menu/), which is a little messier and may require a little more in-depth knowledge.

In my opinion, use the first option.

Comment: hey people i talked about the desktop's right click context menu, where there is also an option of refresh, screen resulation, view, sort by, etc not the windows explorer or some file's or folder's right click.

Comment: It's the same thing. It also is possible that the Graphic's Properties Dialog has an option to remove them. I don't have Intel, but my Nvidia does.

Comment: but my intel dont have that option. :(