# Multiple "Open" In Context Menu (Windows 7)?

Tags: windows-7, context-menu

I have Zend Studio 8.0.1 installed on my computer. But I have a problem with context menu.
I have multiple "Open" in context menu when i try to open PHP file.

Here's what I'm talking about:
[image]

The first three "Open"s are opening the file with Zend Studio. The last "Open" and "Edit" are opening the file with Notepad (default Windows notepad).

How can i get rid of this? I just want one "Open".

Comment: Check out this earlier [post](http://superuser.com/questions/303337/how-to-remove-unimportant-items-from-desktop-right-click-context-menu/303349#303349).

There is a simple tool that allows you to clean up the context menu.  Probably want to have a quick search before posting.  this question comes up a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows: How to remove items from the right click (context) menu?](http://superuser.com/questions/5011/windows-how-to-remove-items-from-the-right-click-context-menu)

Comment: I would be hesitant to close this as a duplicate right away - this may be a bug due to a different problem. Definitely try the solutions in the linked answers, and comment here to let us know what happened.

Comment: Already solved the problem with "Default Programs Editor" - wonderful tool. However it is still strange how I got almost 3 same "Open"s. Thanks anyway.