# How did the "napiprojekt" entry get into my txt file context menu?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry, malware, context-menu

I noticed today that if I rightclick a txt file there is a context menu entry saying "napiprojekt".

[image: napiprojekt entry]

I googled it but could only find out that it has to do something with subtitles.

I do not remember installing this on purpose, and I definitly have nothing called napiprojekt installed currently.

How did this end up in my context menu? Is there any common software that installs this registry entry? Or might malware be involved?

And how do I remove it?

Answer (score 2):

It isn't Malware.  It is a program that allows you to download subtitles easily for movies.  So... if you selected a movie called "Inception.avi" and right clicked on it, and then clicked on that "napiprojekt" the net would be searched, and a text file would appear in the same directory.  That text file would contain the subtitles for "Inception.avi".

That's the theory, any way.

[The Original Polish site](http://www.napiprojekt.pl/)

[A Napi Clone](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bashnapi/)

As to how you got it... you have provided no history as to how frequently you download movies, or whether you rip and convert DVDs to AVI files, etc.  Who knows... it could have been included with an obscure codec pack that you installed at one time.  However, as I said, it's not Malware or Spyware.  You can try [System Tray Cleaner](http://www.system-tray-cleaner.com/systray/programs.php?appid=69F771BEBE567DC8DFE553E89916B4730025BE00) to get rid of it.

Comment: I did not install any dvd rip software or codec packs, so I'm really not sure how I could've gotten this. All I have in this area are media players (XBMC, VLC etc).

Comment: It is possible it was installed along side something else, but since it doesn't do anything on it's own, and it doesn't track your online habits, and it isn't promoting the purchase of other software, it isn't doing anything bad to your computer.  This is why it is not malware or spyware.  Was there some point where you were looking for subtitles for a movie you downloaded?

Comment: After running into this myself I traced my steps through a month or so of pseudo-random installations and confirmed that the Open Subtitles MKV player (http://www.opensubtitles.us/opensubtitles-player) installs this context menu entry under the key associated with (Default) in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt, which in my case was HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\UltraEdit.txt\shell\napiprojekt.

Oddly, this key points to C:\Program Files (x86)\NAPI-PROJEKT\napisy.exe which, for whatever reason, never got installed on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it's a malware or not, but you should see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now) and answers to it. You may have installed it accidentally.

You can use [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) to inspect and remove this entry from your context menu. Look for the *Product Name* and *Description* columns corresponding to *napiprojekt*.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this as well. No idea how it got there. The button also didn't do anything, I don't have napiprojekt installed anywhere other than the context menu.

I tried the other suggestions without luck. Couldn't find it from any of them.

Tried searching it from regedit locations from [these answers](https://superuser.com/a/39449/1351891), and still couldn't find it.

I got it solved by going to regedit and searching with ctrl + f for napiprojekt, and removing all the instances it could find. Then restart all instances of explorer.exe (I restarted explorer.exe from task manager), and it was fixed.