# Remove Windows built-in items from right-click (context) menu

Tags: windows-7, windows, context-menu

My question is similar to [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/5011/windows-how-to-remove-items-from-the-right-click-context-menu), except mine differs in one part:

> The right click (context) menu is minimal and clean on a fresh installation of Windows

I have to disagree. There are at least 5 context-menu items in a "clean" install of Windows I never use:

[image]

It wouldn't be such a big deal if I didn't later want to add at least 6 more items to the menu (Vim, 7-zip, Tortoise HG/Git/SVN, etc.). Between the built-in items and my additions, there's almost two dozen items, and that's when it really starts to feel bloated.

Is there any way to remove the Windows built-in items from the right-click context menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with Windows contextual menus, it's only possible to manipulate shell *extensions* through the use of 3rd party software and/or registry hacks.  However, these particular options are not extensions - they are hardcoded into the Windows operating system itself, so you will not be able to remove or hide them.

Answer (score 0):

I was gonna ask a similar question about the Windows 7 "Extract all..." right-click option, and apparently there's a hack to remove it!

Here's how: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3233-extract-all-context-menu-add-remove-windows.html

Don't know about the other context menu items though...