# Remove Double Entries from Windows Context Menu

Tags: windows

Whenever I right-click on my Windows desktop to open the context menu, I have two identical entries in it.

[image: Context Menu]

How can I remove the extra entries?

Comment: Remove the entry manually and/or uninstall the software that added them in the first place.  This indicates you have two separate versions of your display driver installed. Likely cause by the fact you didn't uninstall it before you try installing a previous version.

Comment: @Ramhound How do you remove entries manually?

Comment: @Ramhound Never mind, figured it out. Go ahead and post your comment as an answer and I will accept it if you want.

Comment: **I am not going to post an answer that only says to uninstall oftware.**

Comment: use CCleaner to remove context menu items?

Comment: Related: [How to remove items from the right click (context) menu in Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/5011/358766)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find in your registry following key-

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers

you will see a key named "igfxcui"
in your case you will find these keys 2 times (or may be similar named, cause it seems that one is older and one is newer version!

export those two keys(in case of you lost it)

First delete one of those keys,and check your context menu,is satisfied,then good,if not then restore the exported keys and delete the other one!

or you may use these tools -

[ShellMenuView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html)
[image: ShellMenuView]

[Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx)

[image: Autoruns]

(In Autoruns,Go to explorer tab to enable or disable context menu items)

Comment: Although I was able to fix the problem by uninstalling the software and reinstalling it, I am going to accept your answer since what you are showing me here is more along the lines of what I was looking for.

Comment: Then you should also mark one up for last answer magicandre1981!
first i're gonna telling you to uninstall,but it was previously mentioned :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer of Ramhound:

> Remove the entry manually and/or uninstall the software that added
>   them in the first place. This indicates you have two separate versions
>   of your display driver installed. Likely cause by the fact you didn't
>   uninstall it before you try installing a previous version.