# Remove some menu options from context menu

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, context-menu

I know there is a general answer to this question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/5011/windows-how-to-remove-items-from-the-right-click-context-menu), but my question is a little more specific, how to remove the **"Turn on Bitlocker.. "** entry from it(when I right click on a partition), sometimes I might click it accidentally and it is very annoying. I tried to locate the entry for this item in registry but I couldn't. Would anyone help me?

UPDATE: Some(Moab) told me to disable BitLocker, but I do not want to disable the service because I may use it sometimes. And the recommendation Psycogeek to use Autoruns doesn't because there is no entry for BitLocker.

Comment: Disable the bitlocker drive encryption service in Services, Control Panel>Admin Tools>Services

Comment: @Moab But I do have to use Bitlocker sometimes?

Comment: Add that info to your question above.

Comment: Disable the feature and when you want the feature enable it.

Answer (score 4):

Use the AutoRuns program from sysinternals , it shows most of that stuff, and you can save out a configuration, then disable , and load back the saved if you did it wrong.   It covers most all of the shell extention and context menu items.  I am not totally positive how partition only items show, but it should be in the explorer tab.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx

[image]

Comment: I think I should prefer to do it from registry, not by using any 3^rd party software, but I appreciate your response.

Comment: I will give it a try if I could not find another solution.

Comment: There is no entry for Bitlocker?