# How to rearrange or remove items in Google Chrome's right-click context menu in OS X?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, context-menu

Here is what Chrome's context menu looks like right now for me:

[image]

Is it possible to move `Inspect Element` to the bottom of the menu? Or is it possible to remove the bottom two menu items? I never add stuff to Evernote from the browser, and I don't use iTunes' Spoken Track feature. I am aware of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/5011/windows-how-to-remove-items-from-the-right-click-context-menu) post, but the solutions are specifically for Windows.

Comment: Considering there are chrome extensions to mess with the context menu, we just need someone to write an extension to edit the default behavior and or remove default items.

Answer (score 3):

The "inspect element" menu item is a core feature of Chrome with no setting to alter it. Extensions may only add contextual menu items. All three of the items at the bottom of your context-menu can be toggled by through System Preferences in MacOS.

System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services

Uncheck the Services you no longer want to be displayed.Look under "Searching" for "Search With Google' and "Text" for "Add to iTunes as a Spoken Track."