# How to remove the "3D print with 3D Builder" context menu entry in Windows 10?

Tags: context-menu, windows-10-v1607

In Windows 10's Anniversary Update, there is a new "*3D print with 3D Builder*" entry in the context menu of some image file types.

I tried to uninstall the 3D Builder app, but it doesn't remove the context menu entry, and clicking on it reinstalls the app.

I read the related question "[Windows: How to remove items from the right click (context) menu?](https://superuser.com/questions/5011/windows-how-to-remove-items-from-the-right-click-context-menu)" and have tried some of the recommanded applications, as well as less known ones, but, oddly, none of them found this item.

How do I remove this entry from the context menu?

Comment: Surprisingly, I wasn't able to find entries for 3D Builder in [ShellMenuView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html) or [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I monitored what was happening under the hood when right clicking an image file (with the tool Process Monitor from SysInternals), and found out the responsible registry keys.

It is displayed because of the "T3D Print" shell key in bmp, jpg and png file types associations:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\.bmp\Shell\T3D Print
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\.jpg\Shell\T3D Print
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\.png\Shell\T3D Print
```

Deleting them immediately removes the *3D print with 3D Builder* item from the context menu.

Just in case, make sure to backup the keys beforehand, to be able to revert the changes.

Comment: But not the .jpeg extension... that's rather sloppy :P