# Remove "Set as desktop background" from Windows context menu

Tags: windows, context-menu

When I right click an image file in Windows, one of the context menu options is "Set as desktop background". I know some entries can be [hidden with registry edits](https://superuser.com/a/1110620/358766), so I'd like to know if it's possible to remove the "Set as background" option.

Note that while [most context menu entries](https://superuser.com/a/39449/358766) can be found under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\`, the "set as background" option seems to be located somewhere else.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Because my context menu is fairly bloated with excess options, and I have accidentally reset my background to random photos though this menu in the past.

Comment: The question marked as a duplicate is unlikely to be found by anyone looking to remove specifically `Set as desktop background`, but the answer is the same. Use `ShellMenuView` mentioned in the accepted answer to both questions.

Comment: @EricF One doesn't need a reason to ask for the answer to a question. A question can be purely academic. There's no rule against it. Asking "why" is irrelevant and muddies the discussion space.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While it's possible to remove the "Set as desktop background" option by editing the registry manually, it's much easier to do using [ShellMenuView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html).

Simply run the program, search for the Menu Key `setdesktopwallpaper`, and right click each entry to disable them.

[image: Disabling "set desktop background" with ShellMenuView]

If you *do*  want to try manually editing the key with Regedit, it should be listed as `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\.‌​png\Shell\setdesktop‌​wallpaper`. Be warned that removing this key [may disable the ability to change your wallpaper altogether](https://www.sevenforums.com/customization/251855-remove-set-desktop-background-explorer-context-menu.html#post2088759).

Source: [The How-To Geek](https://superuser.com/a/39449/358766)

Comment: This program reference was taken from my answer's reference link...

Comment: I actually found this program from an unrelated answer by [The How-To Geek](https://superuser.com/a/39449/358766). I've amended my answer to give credit to the original source.

Comment: It is worth noting that `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations` is a merged registry view of both the system (HKLM) and user (HKCU) settings so can be used in preference, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724475(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it one of two ways:

**Method 1**

You can modify Windows Registry.

1. Press windows key + R to open Run
2. Type regedit and click ok.
3. Type the following:

   ```
   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers
   ```
4. Each folder inside this registry folder represents an item that is in the context menu. Simply delete the one you do not want. ***You may want to copy the registry value and save it somewhere else in case you ever want to get it back.***

[image]

Be careful about breaking windows and making the ability to switch desktop images still work. You do not want broken windows:

[image]

**Method 2**

Download a context menu editor third party software.

A few that are out there (free):

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/ultimate-windows-customizer

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/right-click-context-menu-extender-for-windows-7-released

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/context-menu-editor-for-windows-7-vista-released

Source for answer:

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/remove-click-context-menu-items-editors

Comment: Tried method 1. [Got the following error](http://i.imgur.com/MS3Llpj.png).

I did find a relevant looking key under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\.png\Shell\setdesktopwallpaper`, but I've read removing this key can [disable the ability to change your wallpaper altogether](https://www.sevenforums.com/customization/251855-remove-set-desktop-background-explorer-context-menu.html#post2088759).

Comment: @StevenVascellaro ha I forgot a step. Look at my answer again. That is probably true about disabling the ability to change the wallpaper again. I would personally go with third party software instead.

Comment: Makes sense. It's worth noting that `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers` doesn't contain any entries about setting desktop background.

Comment: Well usually having Windows run in "ways that Windows wasn't intended to run" can lead to broken windows (punny) :p Hopefully this option at least answered your question and gave you some ideas. If you are satisfied please mark it as your answer

Comment: Very true. Though, for the sake of completion I'd mention that context menu options can be found in registry either at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers` or in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\ `