# How to remove Plastuer from the context menu?

Tags: windows-10, context-menu

I was using Plastuer (an app that displayed HTML5 sites as a desktop wallpaper).
I deleted the app and after a restart, it's context menu entry won't disappear.

I searched at these places inside registry:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFileSystemObjects\ShellE
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers
```

but I had no luck finding an entry with its name.

[image]

Can you help me get rid of it, please?

Comment: Install Plastuer. Install Wise Program Uninstaller. Use the Uninstaller to uninstall Plastuer. Does the entry disappear? (not at my PC right now so can’t make this an answer!

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321 Thanks for the suggestion but that didn't work. It deleted two Registry entries but not the context menu item!

Comment: Related: [How to remove items from the right click (context) menu in Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/5011/358766)

Comment: @StevenVascellaro This was the first thing I tried. Didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use CCleaner to see if it can remove the item.

Remove Windows Context Menu Items with CCleaner:
https://www.groovypost.com/howto/clean-windows-right-click-context-menu/

Comment: No, CCleaner cannot find the entry either...

Answer (score -1):

I found it under 
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\directory\background\shell\Plastuer.

Delete it and seems to be gone.