# Remove item from context menu of folder empty space

Tags: windows, windows-10, context-menu

Similar questions such as [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/5011/how-to-remove-items-from-the-right-click-context-menu-in-windows) have been asked before. However, all of them deal with the context menu upon right-clicking a file. I'm looking to remove entries that show up when you don't right click any file at all.

[image: Screenshot of context menu]

In particular, I'm looking to remove the Visual Studio, Atom and Git entries, or at least move them to the extended context menu (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right click</kbd>)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Follow these steps...

Open the Registry Editor by opening Run (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) and then entering `REGEDIT`.
Navigate to this directory: `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell`

[image]

Delete unwanted directories. For example, in here, I'm deleting Visual Studio and Git options from the right-click by deleting AnyCode and git directories. Make sure to back up your registry in case something went wrong. (`Right-Click` > `Export`)

[image]

Now you might be able to see the changes in the right-click menu. If not please restart the PC.

[image]

You can also add new keys if you want.

For more information, please refer this website: https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/windows-right-click-context-menu/

How to Open Registry Editor: https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-open-registry-editor-2625150
How to Back up the Windows Registry: https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-back-up-the-windows-registry-2625146