# Get rid of Paint 3D-related mess from Windows 10

Tags: windows-10-v1903, paint-3d-preview

I have uninstalled Paint 3D [the usual way](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-uninstall-paint-3d-app-in-windows-10):

[image]

And I have even repeated this attempt by using elevated Power Shell:

```
Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.MSPaint | Remove-AppxPackage
```

But the junk added with Paint 3D to my system is left over. In context menus:

[image]

And in "regular" Paint:

[image]

Clicking any of these always ends with:

[image]

Which is pretty much annoying. How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to remove items from the right click context menu, there is a pretty [good answer](https://superuser.com/a/39449/880618) that explains in detail on how to do it. I personally like [ShellExView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) but registry changes seem to be more effective.

Not all apps are equal so in order to remove it from the context menu [via registry](https://www.askvg.com/windows-10-tip-remove-edit-with-paint-3d-option-from-image-context-menu/) you need to delete the following keys:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.3mf\Shell\3D Edit
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.bmp\Shell\3D Edit
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.fbx\Shell\3D Edit
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.gif\Shell\3D Edit
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.jfif\Shell\3D Edit
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.jpe\Shell\3D Edit
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.jpeg\Shell\3D Edit
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.jpg\Shell\3D Edit
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.png\Shell\3D Edit
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.tif\Shell\3D Edit
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.tiff\Shell\3D Edit
```

Please make sure to backup your registry before changing anything.

As for the Paint app, an topic suggests that the option is [hard-coded](https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/111166-paint-remove-open-paint-3d-within-ms-paint.html) in it.

The answer down here is still valid but you can [download it](https://winaero.com/blog/download-classic-paint-windows-10/) instead.

---

You can however use a older version of it following these steps (you need a system that is running version 1709 or lower):

> There are two files you require: mspaint.exe and mspaint.exe.mui. The first can be found in C:\Windows\System32\ the .mui file is in a language-specific sub-folder of System32, for a US English install that would be C:\Windows\System32\en-US (for me it's C:\Windows\System32\en-GB).
>
> Copy mspaint.exe to a folder of your choice (I have made a 'C:\Program Files\Old Windows apps' folder). Create the en-us (or en-gb, etc.) subfolder in your chosen folder and put a copy of mspaint.exe.mui there. You can now create a shortcut to run Paint from this folder.
>
> The advantage of using a folder other than System32 is that your mspaint will never get replaced/removed by an upgrade. In fact, you can keep different versions in separate folders and run them simultaneously if you wish, as I have done here with the 1709 and a previous version.
>
> [Source](https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/111166-paint-remove-open-paint-3d-within-ms-paint.html#post1382107)

Comment: Thank you for a perfect answer. The alternative / older version of solution's steps is not for me, as I am using 1903 (as denoted by tag in question). But, thank you, because this can be fruitful for others.