# Unremovable items from New right-click menu

Tags: windows-10, context-menu

I would like to remove the `Text Document` and `Bitmap image` items from the context menu's `New` menu, but I am unable to find the items in the Registry. I was able to remove other items from the `New` menu, but these two items don't seem to be stored in the same place as other new item shortcuts:

- I looked in both `HKCR\.bmp` and `HKCR\.txt`, with neither having the `ShellNew` key, nor are they stored within:

  ```
  HKCR\*\shell
  HKCR\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers
  HKCR\AllFileSystemObjects\ShellEx
  HKCR\Directory\shell
  HKCR\Directory\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers
  ```
- I used Nirsoft's [ShellMenuNew](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_new.html) and `Bitmap Image` and `Text Document` do not appear
- I have tried the suggestions listed in this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/5011/how-to-remove-items-from-the-right-click-context-menu-in-windows) and  How-To Geek [article](https://www.howtogeek.com/426985/how-to-remove-items-from-the-new-menu-in-windows-explorer/)

Comment: there should be a key (folder) directly under HKCR that matches what you want to remove>>>>https://www.howtogeek.com/426985/how-to-remove-items-from-the-new-menu-in-windows-explorer/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove items from the right click (context) menu in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/5011/how-to-remove-items-from-the-right-click-context-menu-in-windows)

Comment: Yes, I tried the suggestions in the article and previous SuperUser question. I've clarified that in my post

Comment: I suggest you not try to remove these. The next major update or any repair you have to do because of operating system errors will just put the features back.

Comment: @John Why would you suggest not customizing the _New_ context menu? While removed items will be added back twice a yr from the biannual update _(essentially a Repair install)_, it's as easy as merging a `.reg` file to add the customization back. The only other way they could be auto-added back is by performing a System Restore from a restore point taken prior to the change, as `SFC` and `DISM` have no way to modify Registry hives since hives aren't static, having no backups within the Component Store [`%WinDir%\WinSxS`]. _(I heavily customize all Context Menus via Yamicsoft's Win10 Manager.)_

Comment: I too customize the CRAP out of my menus.  If I left them because Microsoft might put them back then I wouldn't enjoy me computer nearly as much as I do.  Well worth the 4 minute investment of tweaking the menus.

Answer (score 3):

Found an answer to this at [Windows ElevenForum](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/removing-bitmap-image-from-new-context-menu.2412/post-54492). It has to do with the fact that Notepad and Paint are now UWP apps. To remove the context menu entries, you have to uninstall Notepad and Paint. There is another way, but it requires mucking into the apps themselves.

> To remove .txt and .bmp from `Create > New Context Menu` without removing notepad and paint components from Windows.
>
> For Paint Open
> *C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Paint_11.2110.0.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxManifest.xml*
>
> For Notepad Open
> *C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsNotepad_10.2103.7.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\AppxManifest.xml*
>
> And remove the line starting with **<uap:FileType uap4:ShellNewFileName=**

Note that C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ can't be edited with user or even administrator and the change will most likely get reset each time there's a new app version released.

Comment: hope for better solutions.

Comment: How are you supposed to open or edit the AppxManifest.xml files? Every time I try I get an "Access is denied" error, even if I perform the action as Admin, _even if I perform the action as SYSTEM by using PsExec_. If System User can't edit the file, how is it supposed to be done??

Answer (score 0):

Renaming `HKCR\.txt\ShellNew` to `HKCR\.txt\xShellNew` [likewise with `.bmp`] was sufficient to remove the entry from the context menu: [image: Screenshot]

`ShellNew` keys I found on my computer:

```powershell
PS HKCR:\>> gci -s | ? PSCHildName -eq 'ShellNew' | select -expand name

  HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.api\AcroExch.Plugin\ShellNew
  HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.contact\ShellNew
  HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.fdf\AcroExch.FDFDoc\ShellNew
  HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.library-ms\ShellNew
  HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.lnk\ShellNew
  HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.odg\LibreOffice.DrawDocument.1\ShellNew
  HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.odp\LibreOffice.ImpressDocument.1\ShellNew
  HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ods\LibreOffice.CalcDocument.1\ShellNew
  HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.odt\LibreOffice.WriterDocument.1\ShellNew
  HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pdx\PDXFileType\ShellNew
  HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.rtf\ShellNew
  HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.secstore\AcroExch.SecStore\ShellNew
  HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xdp\AcroExch.XDPDoc\ShellNew
  HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xfdf\AcroExch.XFDFDoc\ShellNew
  HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.zip\CompressedFolder\ShellNew
  HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{a5a3563a-5755-4a6f-854e-afa3230b199f}\ShellNew
  HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\ShellNew
  HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\CLSID\{a5a3563a-5755-4a6f-854e-afa3230b199f}\ShellNew
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, HKCR\.txt\ShellNew and HKCR\.bmp\ShellNew doesn't exists in my registry

Comment: Actually, you never mention the key name: "`ShellNew`'! If it was mentioned in any linked content, you shold have quoted the relevant part!

Comment: @JW0914 : While I appreciate typo corerections (damn near blind here), I don't think you should edit the output in a screen capture to something the command will never actually output --- call me old-fashioned that way!

Comment: Here it is from the question `I looked in both HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bmp and HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt. Neither has the ShellNew key`

Comment: I lokked for the word several times & did not see it. My retinas are dying. sorry.

Comment: @KeithMiller I didn't think about it that way, great point =]

Comment: @JW0914: Make up your mind! :D

Comment: @KeithMiller I thought you'd have made the edit after you pointed that out, but when I came across this earlier today and saw it hadn't been, I wanted to change it because you made a great point

Answer (score 0):

To remove:

- **Bitmap Image:**

  ```powershell
  # PowerShell $env:UserProfile variable used | Cmd: Replace with %UserProfile%

  # Backup key within the Registry and delete:
    Reg Copy "HKCR\.bmp\ShellNew" "HKCR\.bmp\CustomDisabled\ShellNew" /s /f
    Reg Delete "HKCR\.bmp\ShellNew"
      # To restore:
        Reg Copy "HKCR\.bmp\CustomDisabled\ShellNew" "HKCR\.bmp\ShellNew" /s /f

  # Backup key within a file and delete:
    MkDir "$env:UserProfile\Documents\RegistryBackup"
    Reg Export "HKCR\.bmp\ShellNew" "$env:UserProfile\Documents\RegistryBackup\bmp-ShellNew.reg"
    Reg Delete "HKCR\.bmp\ShellNew"
      # To restore:
        Reg Import "$env:UserProfile\Documents\RegistryBackup\bmp-ShellNew.reg"
  ```
- **Text Document:**

  ```powershell
  # PowerShell $env:UserProfile variable used | Cmd: Replace with %UserProfile%

  # Backup key within the Registry and delete:
    Reg Copy "HKCR\.txt\ShellNew" "HKCR\.txt\CustomDisabled\ShellNew" /s /f
    Reg Delete "HKCR\.txt\ShellNew"
      # To restore:
        Reg Copy "HKCR\.txt\CustomDisabled\ShellNew" "HKCR\.txt\ShellNew" /s /f

  # Backup key within a file and delete:
    MkDir "$env:UserProfile\Documents\RegistryBackup"
    Reg Export "HKCR\.txt\ShellNew" "$env:UserProfile\Documents\RegistryBackup\txt-ShellNew.reg"
    Reg Delete "HKCR\.txt\ShellNew"
      # To restore:
        Reg Import "$env:UserProfile\Documents\RegistryBackup\txt-ShellNew.reg"
  ```

---

### References:

- [**`Reg`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg): [`Copy`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-copy) | [`Delete`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-delete) | [`Export`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-export) | [`Import`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-import)
- Default `HKCR\.bmp` and `HKCR\.txt` keys:

  ```powershell
  Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

  [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bmp]
  @="Paint.Picture"
  "Content Type"="image/bmp"
  "PerceivedType"="image"

  [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bmp\OpenWithList]

  [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bmp\OpenWithList\MSPaint.exe]
  @=""

  [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bmp\OpenWithProgids]
  "AppX2jm25qtmp2qxstv333wv5mne3k5bf4bm"=hex(0):
  "AppX43hnxtbyyps62jhe9sqpdzxn1790zetc"=hex(0):
  "AppXcdh38jxzbcberv50vxg2tg4k84kfnewn"=hex(0):
  "Paint.Picture"=""

  [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bmp\PersistentHandler]
  @="{098f2470-bae0-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"

  [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bmp\ShellNew]
  "ItemName"=hex(2):40,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,57,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,6f,00,77,00,\
    73,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,6d,00,73,\
    00,70,00,61,00,69,00,6e,00,74,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,2c,00,2d,00,35,00,\
    39,00,34,00,31,00,34,00,00,00
  "NullFile"=""

  [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt]
  @="txtfile"
  "Content Type"="text/plain"
  "PerceivedType"="text"

  [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\OpenWithProgids]
  "VSCode.txt"=""

  [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\PersistentHandler]
  @="{5e941d80-bf96-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"

  [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt\ShellNew]
  "ItemName"=hex(2):40,00,25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,\
    6f,00,74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,\
    00,6e,00,6f,00,74,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,64,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,2c,00,\
    2d,00,34,00,37,00,30,00,00,00
  "NullFile"=""
  ```

Comment: HCKR\.txt and HCK\.bmp does not exists in my Registry

Comment: @RHPT They've been manually removed then. I've added the default `.reg` file for both, but if importing the default keys, then removing `ShellNew`, does not fix your problem, perform a Repair Install, as something in the hives is likely corrupted since those are the keys for the _New_ context menu. You can try using Yamicsoft's [Win10 Manager](https://yamicsoft.com/windows10manager/product.html)'s Context Menu Manager _(under Customizations section - free full-use 20-day trial)_ before doing a Repair Install, which is what I use to heavily customize all context menus.

Comment: I apologize. I meant to say that `HKCR\.txt\ShellNew` and `HKCR\.bmp\ShellNew` doesn't exists in my Registry

Comment: @RHPT Something odd is going on with the `HKCR` hive - you can try using [`RegEditX`](https://www.dcsoft.com/products/regeditx/)'s RegCrawler to search for the hex output of `ShellNew` to determine if there's another key that's been misnamed somewhere. Does selecting either of those New menu items open Paint and Notepad?

Comment: Yes, selecting those new menu items creates a new empty text message and a bitmap image file