# Remove "Convert to Adobe PDF" from context menu

Tags: windows-explorer, adobe-acrobat, context-menu

When I right click a .docx file in Windows' File Explorer, there's an entry 'Convert to Adobe PDF' in the context menu. I'd like to remove the entry, but keep Adobe Acrobat installed.
What I've tried:

- Removed all Adobe subkeys from `HKCR\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers`
- Ensured there is no Adobe subkeys under `HKCR\.docx\shellex`
- Disabled everything Adobe in [Autoruns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns)
- Disabled everything Adobe in [ShellExView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html)

Restarted my computer after each step.

What else could be causing this entry to show?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151045/discussion-on-question-by-wezten-remove-convert-to-adobe-pdf-from-context-menu); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### For the Windows 10 Context Menu

There's a very lightweight app called [Easy Context Menu](https://www.sordum.org/7615/easy-context-menu-v1-6/), which will apply the necessary registry changes. Its website is an advertising mess, but here's a [Direct download link](https://www.sordum.org/downloads/?easy-context-menu).

- Once unzipped, start the exe. No install needed.
- Open `File -> ContextMenu Cleaner` .
- Search for the entry `Adobe.Acrobat.ContextMenu.`, where beside it says `Folder`.
- Deactivate.
- Done. The effect is immediate.

[image]

### For the Windows 11 Context Menu

The Windows 11 Context menu item is not anymore saved in the Registry, but it is connected to a `.dll` file.

- Navigate to `C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat Elements`
- Rename or delete the file `ContextMenuIExplorerCommandShim.dll`
- The effect is immediate.

Source: a [thread on elevenforum](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/how-to-remove-this-from-the-new-context-menu.4457/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with a .reg file which deletes the registry key:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\Adobe.Acrobat.ContextMenu]

;deletes Adobe Acrobat context menu entry
```

Save all the contents into a .reg file, double click it and press Yes when prompted. Keep the comment in the file - there must exist a line after the last command for the .reg file to execute properly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have **Acrobat**, so can't check directly, but there are two other registry keys you should check. `HKCR\SystemFileAssociations` contains entries that persist for a given filetype *regardless of the extension's `AppID`/`Open with` association*. In addition to file extensions, there are subkeys that correspond to the various `Kind` types and serve as a "roll-up" for multiple extensions. So check under:

- `HKCR\SystemFileAssociations\.docx`
- `HKCR\SystemFileAssociations\document`

Good luck!!